# Angular How to select (highlight) text in an input field

Tags: angular

My company uses a typeahead search query. I've implemented a feature where if the list of results returns only 1 item, that 1 item is selected.

after this auto-selection happens, I want to have the text in the input box be automatically highlighted so that the user can immediately type and the previous words will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Use input[.select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) after you've done the auto-selection.

Comment: Do I do this in my component.ts file or in the HTML?

Comment: You'll do this in the component.ts.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's my companies unique logic, but what do you mean by 'input'?

Comment: You will have to reference the input element on the DOM that you highlighted, that's what I mean by input. If you shared relevant code within both your `.ts` and `.html` files I could provide a concrete example, if you still need.